# Another way of conditioning the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw the block of SQL below in an article in [this](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/after-trigger-instead-of-trigger-example) page:

```
select @empname = d.Emp_Name 
from deleted d
```

How do you put something like `@empname = d.Emp_Name` in a `SELECT` statement?

What does it do? Is it another way of conditioning, instead of using `WHERE` clause?

Plus, it seems to be in SQL Server, but just to be sure, isn't it something that can be done in MySQL or some other DBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign to a variable this way...

...but this is probably a mistake. This assignment convention is typically used only when you expect exactly one row. However, the `deleted` table name indicates a likely trigger, and SQL Server will sometimes batch up individual deletions in a single call to the trigger, such that the table has multiple rows. Therefore this trigger is likely not correctly processing some deletions.

Comment: `deleted` is also for use in the `OUTPUT` clauses of T-SQL’s `UPDATE`, `MERGE`, and `DELETE` statements, not just inside `TRIGGER` objects. It could also be the name of a derived-table or CTE.

Comment: @Dai hence the "probably". But even that is more than I needed. The link in the question's first sentence definitely indicates a trigger.

Comment: Right - I was just elucidating for those reading this who are unfamiliar with T-SQL’s _kinda-cool_-parts (as opposed to just its painful parts)

Comment: yes, this actually explains how we can access the `NEW` or `OLD` column values in the trigger